# Problem creating evil twin using airbase-ng

Tags: wireless-networking, man-in-the-middle, sniffing

I am trying to create an evil twin access point using airbase-ng.I am creating a hotspot using my mobile and connecting anther mobile to this hotspot.Now I am trying to create an evil twin access point(replica of my mobile) using airbase-ng on my linux system.When I give the command:

```
sudo airbase-ng -a <bssid of my mobile> --essid <my mobile's(created) ssid> -c 1 wlan0mon
```

I get as output:

```
20:01:00  Created tap interface at0
20:01:00  Trying to set MTU on at0 to 1500
20:01:00  Access Point with BSSID <my mobile's(created) ssid> started.
Error: Got channel -1, expected a value > 0.
```

I am getting an error while creating the twin.
I don't know why it is not able to create a AP with a non-negative channel.

Can anybody help?
Thanks

Comment: Try adding the parameter --ignore-negative-one, or install the patches which defines this.

Comment: Try disabling all the other interfaces.

Comment: Does the card even support AP mode?